# C program to give output as last name first then first name

Tags: c

In C programming,how to write a program,which on entering the name gives output as last name first then first name?
 for example
input - faiz anwar
output- anwar faiz

Comment: Do you know how to do it in a different language? can you post the algorithm at least?

Comment: Scan two strings,store them in two arrays,print the second array first and then the first. Simple!

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char first_name[32];
    char last_name[32];
    scanf("%31s %31s", first_name, last_name);
    printf("%s %s\n", last_name, first_name);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
char full_name[64];
char first_name[32];
char last_name[32];
scanf("%63[^\n]", full_name);//fgets(full_name, sizeof(full_name), stdin);
sscanf(full_name, "%31s %31s", first_name, last_name);
printf("%s %s\n", last_name, first_name);
```

Comment: bluepixy,my question was not this,u have to enter your full nname in a string,then the output should be written as last name,then first name

Comment: @saquibanwar It seems to accept the same input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the line into a buffer using `fgets()`
2. Break the line into tokens using `strtok()`
3. Save the tokens into a array using `strcpy()` and print the array from `last_idx` to `0`.
4. This applies generally to a line of input instead of just 2 strings.